# Binding ObservableCollection index

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I using json web server to retrieve data and put it into `ObservableCollection` that I bind it into my xaml, so i want to show index like

1. xxxx
2. xxxxxxx

How i can get number 1, 2 and so on?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `DataGrid` then in that case you need to enable `DisplayRowNumber` property and in the `LoadingRow` event of DataGrid you can set `Row.Header` with the index property. Code can be like

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" LoadingRow="OnLoadingRow" behaviors:DataGridBehavior.DisplayRowNumber="True" ItemsSource="{Your Binding}" />

void OnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex() + 1).ToString(); 
}
```

Edit: As you want this for `ListBox`, so I suggest you to please check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e61697d8-0f76-4b8c-a422-8fb8b108217f/number-prefix-for-listbox-item?forum=wpf) solution. In this user is creating Index field and binding that with the ListBox.

```
Index = myCollection.ToList().IndexOf(e)
```

Also you can check [Hannes](http://weblogs.asp.net/hpreishuber/archive/2008/11/18/rownumber-in-silverlight-datagrid-or-listbox.aspx) blog post as well. He is showing example for Silverlight but it will work with WPF also.

Comment: no, i want to use it in my listbox and also into my map pushpin

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using **[IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** which will return index.

**XAML**

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}">
  <ListBox.Resources>
     <local:RowIndexConverter x:Key="RowIndexConverter"/>
  </ListBox.Resources>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
           <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RowIndexConverter}">
              <Binding/>
              <Binding ElementName="listBox" Path="ItemsSource"/>
            </MultiBinding>
         </TextBlock.Text>
      </TextBlock>
     </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Converter**:

```
public class RowIndexConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        IList list = (IList)values[1];
        return list.IndexOf(values[0]).ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
                                object parameter,
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't understand this part {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                           AncestorType=ListBoxItem}

Comment: We need to pass converter a `ListBoxItem` so that we can find its index in ListBox. ListBoxItem is visual parent of TextBlock so with RealtiveSource we are telling binding engine to travel up the visual tree to get parent ListBoxItem and pass it to converter. Read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Error at what location? Have you change `YourCollection` with your `ObservableCollection instance` in xaml file?

Comment: error at AncestorType, it say that relativesource does not have AncestorType

Comment: Oh i forgot `AncestorType` doesn't exist in Windows phone. I posted it for WPF sample. However, i have posted another solution. You can use ElementName. Also converter needs to be modified accordingly.